# Dump and restore mongo db with python

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, shell

Hello I have a simple script that dumps a mongo db using a shell command from a remote mongo server, and then runs a shell command to restore that db to the dev db on another server.

the script lives in /home/ubuntu/mongo and the dump is in /home/ubuntu/mongo/dump

here is my code:

## !/usr/bin/python

```
import time
import subprocess
import os
import shutil

now=int(time.time())
cmd="mongodump --host  -db chronotrack"
print subprocess.check_output(cmd,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)

cmd="mongorestore --host   -db chronotrack  dump/"
print subprocess.check_output(cmd,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)

#mongorestore --host  --port 3017 --db mongodevdb --username mongodevdb --password YourSecretPwd --drop /backup/dump
```

Here is my error:

```
ERROR: root directory must be a dump of a single database
       when specifying a db name with --db
usage: mongorestore [options] [directory or filename to restore from]
options:
  --help                  produce help message
  -v [ --verbose ]        be more verbose (include multiple times for more
                          verbosity e.g. -vvvvv)
  --version               print the program's version and exit
  -h [ --host ] arg       mongo host to connect to ( <set name>/s1,s2 for sets)
  --port arg              server port. Can also use --host hostname:port
  --ipv6                  enable IPv6 support (disabled by default)
  -u [ --username ] arg   username
  -p [ --password ] arg   password
  --dbpath arg            directly access mongod database files in the given
                          path, instead of connecting to a mongod  server -
                          needs to lock the data directory, so cannot be used
                          if a mongod is currently accessing the same path
  --directoryperdb        if dbpath specified, each db is in a separate
                          directory
  --journal               enable journaling
  -d [ --db ] arg         database to use
  -c [ --collection ] arg collection to use (some commands)
  --objcheck              validate object before inserting
  --filter arg            filter to apply before inserting
  --drop                  drop each collection before import
  --oplogReplay           replay oplog for point-in-time restore
  --keepIndexVersion      don't upgrade indexes to newest version
```

Comment: btw i removed the hostnames for obvious reasons.

Comment: No need to clarify about the hostnames. We all understand! :)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer :

```
"mongorestore --host  -db chronotrack  --drop dump/chronotrack"
```

Comment: Please explain the answer, for the benefit of future users.

Comment: I assume that in original post op missed name of dump (which is "chronotrack") in "--drop dump/" part and tried to specify only dump destination instead of dump-file itself.